# Can you add an additional entrypoint to servlet web-apps?

Tags: java, web-applications, sockets, jakarta-ee, client-server

Imagine you have a standard java web-app using plain servlets, or SpringMVC, or whatever. You also want (for whatever reason) a way to talk to the server not using HTTP - I'll use direct sockets as it's the easiest example I can think of.

Writing a web-app is easy, you have servlets acting as entrypoints. Writing a java app which monitors ports is also pretty easy. But what about one that does both? Is it allowed without hacking? And if it turns out we agree this is a Bad Idea, what's a better architecture? Note that one of the motivations behind this is performance... we *could* easily have two separate apps sharing a DB but prefer to avoid using the DB as a communication tool, when information could be cached in memory much more efficiently.

Comment: That can make sense. The servlet container can be partly agnostic of HTTP: that's why there is a `ServletRequest` and `HttpServletRequest`.

Answer (score 2):

So I assume there is a Java EE container in play, like Tomcat. If you want it to listen on some other port besides or in addition to 80, sure. You would make a new `Connector` in `server.xml`, in Tomcat's case, and specify whatever port you like.

If you want this connector to speak a custom protocol, you need to implement and register your own customer `Connector`. I've not done it, but seems straightforward.

If you're answering substantially the same requests via two protocols, it makes sense to use one server with different endpoints. I imagine it makes it far easier to share all that common logic.

Even if you want to run a separate app, it still probably pays to go this way, since you'll be leveraging the container's management of connections and such.

Comment: +1 The most well known non-http connector is probably AJP_13, the protocol to connect Apache and Tomcat.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the concept of Connectors, do you have a link to 
an example, or some sample code? In my case, the most likely use case _would_ be a client sending a direct socket message to the server.

Comment: or another example might be that a Flex client wants to talk to the server using BlazeDS, if that can fit into a servlet system... not something I've used before to have a clear idea if it might be possible.